# How to get data from json array in php via ajax get request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have 3 data in my database and I want my js to show all my data, But when I'm using json array, I get an error and my data doesn't show it all.

```
var confurl = "http://localhost:8080/servisppk/web_service.php";
$.ajax({
    url : confurl,
    type : 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend : function() {
        $.mobile.loading('show', {
            text : 'please wait while retrieving data...',
            textVisible : true
        });
    },
    success : function(dataObject) {
        var appendList = '<li><a href="#page-two?id=' + dataObject.NIM + '" target="_self" id="detail-mhs" data-nimmhs="' + dataObject.NIM + '"><h2>' + dataObject.Nama + '</h2><p>' + dataObject.NIM + '</p><p><b>' + dataObject.Fakultas + '</b></P></a></li>';
        $('#list-mhs').append(appendList);
        $('#list-mhs').listview('refresh');
    },
    complete : function(){
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }
});
```

i'm using json array in my php:

```
$ms = array($mhs,$mhs2,$mhs3);
ECHO JSON_ENCODE($ms);
```

when i'm using it, it doesn't show my data at all, it just show that my data is undefined, but when I change it to only be able to read one data, the data can appear even if only one.

changed to this:

```
$ms = $mhs;
ECHO JSON_ENCODE($ms);
```

Comment: can you `var_dump` this `$ms = array($mhs,$mhs2,$mhs3);`

Comment: with `array($mhs,$mhs2,$mhs3);` you create an indexed (not an associative) array. So your `$mhs` will be in `dataObject[0]`, $mhs2  in `dataObject[1]`,.. - This is also why `dataObject.NIM` is undefined. Try `dataObject[0].NIM`.

Comment: What shall be in $ms? Or asked another way: what is in $mhs, $mhs2, $mhs3? Is this 3 datasets or three parameters you want to _combine_ to one dataset?

Comment: "Note: Function names are case-insensitive, though it is usually good form to call functions as they appear in their declaration." - php docs

Comment: There is a chance that you simply need to change to `$ms = array_merge($mhs,$mhs2,$mhs3);` - but without knowing your data it's impossible to answer... So if you need help, It might be wise to answer the questions asked.

Answer (score 0):

You need send header let browser known, like:

```
<?php
$data = ['test' => 'hello'];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```